# Nested Controls and properties

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have a UserControlB which exposes a Title property of type string.
I then have a UserControlA which contains one UserControlB and exposes a property called MyNestedControl which returns the instance of UserControlB.

In my main page I'm declaring a UserControlA and I'm trying to set the value of the Title property as follow MyNestedControl.Title="ABC".

However, Visual Studio throws a compile error saying that Title does not exist on the Type UserControlA.

Is this type of nesting possible through xaml? Please see below the full code.

Many thanks,
Bruno

```
<UserControlB>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" />
</UserControlB>

public partial class UserControlB : UserControl {
  public string Title
  {  
    get { return this.txtBlock.Text; }
    set { this.txtBlock.Text = value; }
  }
}

<UserControlA>
    <local:UserControlB x:Name="userControlB" />
</UserControlA>

public partial class UserControlA : UserControl {
  public UserControlB MyNestedControl
  {
    get { return this.userControlB; }
  }
}

<MainPage>
    <local:UserControlA x:Name="userControlA" MyNestedControl.Title="ABC" />
</MainPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the syntax for attached properties to try to set a 'nested' property.

Silverlight is looking for a 'Title' property defined in the 'MyNestedControl' class for the 'UserControlA' class.

This type is nesting is not possible (nor desireable - you're violating the law of demeter) in Xaml.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to make the properties you want accessible through xaml [DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use CustomControl insted UserControl.